# Mass Actions Disappeared

Tags: magento

I'm writing my own extension and I've extended the grid view of cms_pages `<cms_page_grid>Company_Module_Block_Cms_Page_Grid</cms_page_grid>` then within the my new Grid.php all I have is

```
class Company_Module_Block_Cms_Page_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Grid
{

}
```

for some reason the mass action disappear... if I remove `<cms_page_grid>Company_Module_Block_Cms_Page_Grid</cms_page_grid>` from config.xml then the massactions appear.

Comment: By default there is no massaction for the CMS pages grid, is it added by another extension ?

Comment: holy crap you're right LOL... forgot I was installing other extension for examples on how to modify the cms page section... ugh im an idiot... go ahead and post your answer so I can mark it right... *embarrassed* lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The massaction for the CMS pages grid comes from another extension, defining your own rewrite disables the other one and its features in the meantime

Comment: Thanks bImage... maybe I need to take a break if silly things like this are slipping past me haha